# Creating an animation for materials in code (Unity)

Tags: unity, animation

I have a function where you click on an object and it changes the color and emission of a specific material, every object has multiple materials with different order.

```
var emissionColor = mat.GetColor("_EmissionColor");
List<Material> materials.AddRange(t.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials);

 foreach (var m in materials)
    {
        if (m.name.Equals(matName))
        {
            //Debug.Log(m.name);
            m.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            m.color = mat.color;
            m.SetColor("_EmissionColor", emissionColor);

        }
    }
```

So far I'm changing the color once but I would like to have it transition into a different color every 10 seconds, I tried using the animator but it keeps changing the wrong material. Is there a way to do this animation in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to delete this question because it might help someone else facing this problem. 
Basically I used the code above in a function (ChangeColor) that I call twice with a different mat every time. In order to get that delay I used  `Invoke("ChangeColor", delay);` for the second time that I change the material's color.